# get C-string iterator for std::string container

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, iterator

Suppose I have a std::unordered_map. I need an iterator that goes through the keys of the map but de-reference to a C-style char const* rather than a std::string. Boost::adaptors look like just the thing I need for the first part:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> map{{"one",1},{"two",2}};
for (auto& str : map | boost::adaptors::map_keys) {...}
```

Do I have to write a custom adaptor for the std::string->C-string transformation or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I question the premise. Using `std::string` is way more useful than using `char const*`s.

That said, since you're already using adaptors, you just want [`transformed`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html):

```
for (auto c_str : map | map_keys
                      | transformed(std::mem_fn(&std::string::c_str)))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I did not realize you could use transformed this way, it is just the thing I was looking for. Also, you win for using auto.

Comment: To answer your question, I need standard-layout guarantees for objects I iterate over.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest answer:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::adaptors;

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> map{{"one",1},{"two",2}};
    for (char const* sz : map 
            | map_keys
            | transformed(std::mem_fn(&std::string::c_str))
    ) {
        std::cout << sz << "\n";
    }
}
```

My preferred:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::adaptors;
int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> map{{"one",1},{"two",2}};
    for (char const* sz : map | transformed([](auto const& p) { return p.first.c_str(); }))
    {
        std::cout << sz << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: @Barry not really an issue. Just more typing, I think.

Comment: It's a pity there are no generic lambdas in pre-C++14. Holy Bjarne, that looks beautiful! +1

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have boost handy you can hand-roll it by deriving from the map's iterator:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

struct cstrofkey
: std::unordered_map<std::string, int>::const_iterator
{
    using base_class = std::unordered_map<std::string, int>::const_iterator;
    using value_type = const char*;
    cstrofkey(base_class iter) : base_class(iter) {}

    auto operator*() const
    {
        return (base_class::operator*()).first.c_str();
    }
};


struct cstrkeyrange
{
    cstrkeyrange(const std::unordered_map<std::string, int>& map)
    : _begin(map.cbegin()), _end(map.cend())
    {};

    cstrofkey begin() const { return _begin; }
    cstrofkey end() const { return _end; }

    cstrofkey _begin, _end;
};


int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> map{{"one",1},{"two",2}};


    for (auto str : cstrkeyrange(map)) {
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }   
}
```